# Array in each position successively Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got trouble with arrays. I'm trying to iterate elements for each position in the array using **javascript.**

so, I need to do that on the first position, be a value [1]. On the second position, [2, 3, 4]. on the third position, [5,6,7,8,9] and successively two by two.

My attempt was did a for loop:

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
      console.log(`${i} ${j}`)
    }
}
```

But while looping, the indices (i) repeat with (j).
What to do?

Comment: Where is your array? And what is the expected output? Or are you asking to *create* an array? What is the significance of the number 5 in your code? I don't see how that relates to what you write...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```js
var counting = 1;
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i = i + 2) {
  var str = "";
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    str += `${counting} `;
    counting++;
  }

  console.log(str);
}
```